# "golang.org/x/net/ipv4" working on Mac, but not on Linux

Tags: docker, go, network-programming

I'm using "golang.org/x/net/ipv4" in order to use its SetTTL function. Unfortunately it does not seem to work on Linux, only on Mac, even though the documentation indicates Linux supports all the functions.

Here's a minimal example of the problem, with a Dockerfile:

main.go:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "bufio"
  xnet "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

const Host = "google.com"

func main() {
  var err error
  conn, err := net.Dial("tcp4", Host + ":80")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer conn.Close()
  xconn := xnet.NewConn(conn)
  err = xconn.SetTTL(5)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer xconn.Close()
  fmt.Fprint(conn, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: google.com\r\n\r\n")
  firstLine, err := bufio.NewReader(xconn).ReadString('\n')
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(firstLine)
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.8.1-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add git
RUN go get golang.org/x/net/ipv4
COPY . /go/src/me.com/me/xnetproblem
RUN go install me.com/me/xnetproblem
CMD ["/go/bin/xnetproblem"]
```

I run this command:

```
docker build -t xnet .
```

I get this output:

```
john xnetproblem > docker build -t xnet .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 90.62 kB
Step 1/6 : FROM golang:1.8.1-alpine
[snip]
Step 5/6 : RUN go install me.com/me/xnetproblem
 ---> Running in c3802fe61d63
# me.com/me/xnetproblem
src/me.com/me/xnetproblem/main.go:25: xconn.Close undefined (type *ipv4.Conn has no field or method Close)
src/me.com/me/xnetproblem/main.go:28: cannot use xconn (type *ipv4.Conn) as type io.Reader in argument to bufio.NewReader:
    *ipv4.Conn does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
The command '/bin/sh -c go install me.com/me/xnetproblem' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Using `go install` natively, instead of Docker, the program works on Mac but not on Linux.

Comment: Seeing the CRLF in that string makes me cringe...

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: why? That's the specification

Comment: @JohnT. Can you make sure your version of Go and the checkout of `golang.org/x/net/ipv4` are up to date on your mac? The errors you're seeing in docker are accurate, the code is incorrect.

Comment: @JimB you are right! I ran `go get -u` and the code broke on my Mac. What is it about the code that's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JimB's comment I realized my Mac had an old version of the `ipv4` package installed. After updating I was able to fix the code.

Here's a complete working version:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "bufio"
  "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

const Host = "google.com"

func main() {
  var err error
  conn, err := net.Dial("tcp4", Host + ":80")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer conn.Close()

  if err = ipv4.NewConn(conn).SetTTL(5); err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Fprint(conn, fmt.Sprintf("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %v\r\n\r\n", Host))
  firstLine, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(firstLine)
}
```

Here is the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```